# WSGIPassAuthorization On is not working

Tags: django, apache, authorization, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to serve a django web application on apache2 server with mod_wsgi. My application has **oauth2** authentication system. I send my credentials to server and get my token without any problem. But after that I send:

```
Authorization: Bearer HERE_TOKEN
```

but unfortunately I cannot get the data. I searched on the internet and find a solution. In apache's config file -named httpd.conf- there should have been:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

I added it. But nothing changed. When I check my client app, it shows the requested headers. There is no Authorization header.. How can I send the **Authorization** header to server ?

Comment: I have tried all the options, used VirtualHost, used root folder, put WSGIPassAuthorization into VirtualHost, put it outside.. several options but no way..

Comment: any luck with this? i have as well and can't get it to run.

Comment: Actually it had been fixed when I added WSGIPassAuthorization On into Apache config file. But I had error because at the end of the url of the request, I missed to put "/". I thought Authorization header problem was still going on, but in fact it was correct. Maybe you have that kind of a problem?? @lemonpro

Comment: i got it to work. i added it to my sites-enabled *.conf page in the VirtualHost section. That worked.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your Apache, go to etc/httpd/conf.d folder and open wsgi.conf file. Insert the code within VirtualHost DOM:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is tearing their hair out on this like I was, make sure if you have ssl configured on your site and a separate apache config file for *:443, you have it there as well.

Comment: Should this be a comment instead of an answer?